# Text show over Image Hover

Tags: php, html, css

```
<style>
    /* CSS for the span */
    .hover {
        visibility: hidden;
        width: 120px;
        background-color: black;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 6px;
        padding: 5px 0;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        bottom: 100%;
        left: 96%;
        margin-left: -60px;
    }

    /* CSS for the text containing the span */
    .imagetest {
        position: relative;
    }

    /* CSS for text on hover */
    .imagetest:hover .hover {
        visibility: visible;
        display:inline-block;                
    }
</style>
```

**PHP/HTML**

```
<?php
    echo "<div class='hoverText' align=right><img class='imagetest' src='Files/infoplaceholder.png' height=20 width=20><span class='hover'> See About Page for more info </span></div>";
    echo "<BR>";
?>
```

When I place swap names in the css portion, `imagetest` for `hoverText` it works perfectly fine. The drawback with that method is that the div runs across the whole page and wherever the mouse cursor passes through the div the hover pops up. The hover is just not liking the class I stored on the image. I was wondering why this was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS is trying to select a child element of ".imagetest" that has a class of "hover". Since the span.hover tag is not a child of .imagetest, css will not select it.

Try something like this

```
    <div class='hoverText' align=right>
        <span class='imagetest'>
            <img src='Files/infoplaceholder.png' height=20 width=20 />
            <span class='hover' > See About Page for more info </span>
        </span>
    </div>
```

This will help CSS find the inner span as a child element of .imagetest

Another option would be to use a CSS selector that selects siblings

```
.imagetest:hover + .hover {
    visibility: visible;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[See a list of CSS selectors at W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)